# How to force an ADX to update from source with all historical data

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

Does anyone know a way to force a child table to update from the source table? it would be a one off command to run when the child table is created, then we have an auto update policy in place.

Googling suggests to try this, however it produces a syntax error

```
.update policy childTable with (sourceTable)
```

Thanks!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had to use this:

```
.append childTable <| updateFunction
```

Answer (score 0):

Update policy is a mechanism that works during the ingestion and does not support backfill.

You can consider using [materialized view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/materialized-views/materialized-view-overview) with [backfill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/materialized-views/materialized-view-create#backfill-a-materialized-view) property (if your transformation logic falls under the limitations) or create the child table based on a query, using the [.set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-ingestion/ingest-from-query) command.
If your source table is huge you might need to split it to multiple commands.

Comment: Thank you, we had to use the append as the table had been made